# merged angular js app to mvc 5, and i keep getting this error

Tags: .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

is it still correct to have my module written this way? the output is just showing ; ; and in console there is this error

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angularFormsApp.config(
["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "app/Home.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            })
            .when("/newAccountForm", {
                templateUrl: "app/AccountForm/afTemplate.html",
                controller: "afController"
            })
            .when("/updateAccount/:id", {
                templateUrl: "app/AccountForm/afTemplate.html",
                controller: "afController"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/home"
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

and these are my bundles

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/asha/style").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Content/app.css"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/asha/script").Include(
        "~/Scripts/angular.js",
        "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
        "~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui.bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "~/app/AngularFormsApp.js",
        "~/app/DataService.js",
        "~/app/ValidationDirective.js",
        "~/app/EmployeeForm/efController.js",
        "~/app/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Comment: can you please eleborate what is it your are trying to console, since this is an injector module error, which means either angular-router.js or ui.bootstrap paths are wrong.

Comment: yes you are correct, fixed it by checking all the names from script folder of my MVC, thanks thanks mate cheers!

Comment: you are welcome, please like my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

since this is an injector module error which means either **angular-router.js** OR **ui.bootstrap** paths are wrong.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr
```